# Resource does not exist error on hasura while github ci cd

Tags: github, continuous-integration, hasura, hasura-jwt, hasura-docker

I am trying to setup github ci cd with hasura...

I did everything as [document](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/cloud/projects/github-integration.html) said so, but since I am applying change locally on database, on cloud deployment it is saying table already exist while applying migration (which is logically correct).
[image]

**now I want to avoid, skip or sync migration between cloud and local for that hasura mentioned a [command in same doc](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/cloud/projects/github-integration.html#error-applying-migrations).**

**While executing this command I am getting resource not found error**

**command:** `hasura migrate apply --skip-execution --version 1631602988318 --endpoint "https://customer-support-dev.hasura.app/v1/graphql" --admin-secret 'mySecretKey'`

**error:** `time="2021-09-14T20:44:19+05:30" level=fatal msg="{\n \"path\": \"$\",\n \"error\": \"resource does not exist\",\n \"code\": \"not-found\"\n}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake `--endpoint` must not contain URL path. So its value will be `https://customer-support-dev.hasura.app`.